# Error in installing package in R: .rs.Env

Tags: r, rstudio

I am getting the following error every time I try to install any package in `R`:

> Error in install.packages : unused arguments (assign(fullName, var,
>   .rs.Env), environment(.rs.Env[[fullName]]) <- .rs.Env)

I tried reinstalling, as well as updating the version, but I am still getting the same error .

Comment: Are you installing in R or RStudio? I believe `.rs.Env` is an internal RStudio-specific environment.

Comment: I am installing in RStudio